# Build logistic regression models for each PAIR of 10 classes

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, subset, logistic-regression

I am working on MNIST [digit recognizer](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/) dataset

Here, I have 10 class labels and I am looking to build and compare all the pairs of classes, ie, to run 10c2 logistic regression models and compare them. I know I could use
 `combn(unique(mnist$label), 2, function(x) , simplify = TRUE)` 
in a loop and write the model in function. But, Im stuck here.

```
loglist <- list()
for(i in unique(mnist$label)){ 
        tmp <- try(append(loglist, glm(label~.,family=binomial(link=logit),
                   data = mnist[mnist$label == i, ])))
        if (class(tmp) != "try-error") loglist <- append(loglist, tmp)
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be of great help, Thank you.

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: code doesnt work, m unable to debugg or find a shorter way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to use logistic regression models for multiple (10 in your case) classes.

1. One vs rest
2. One vs One

These two methods have good explanation on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) and have good [video lecture](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/38) by Andrew NG.

Another Approach would be to use **Softmax Regression**, A [good tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression) can be find at given link. This model generalizes logistic regression to classification problems where the class label y can take on more than two possible values.

So, which model to use when :

> This will depend on whether the four classes are mutually exclusive.
>   For example, if your four classes are classical, country, rock, and
>   jazz, then assuming each of your training examples is labeled with
>   exactly one of these four class labels, you should build a softmax
>   classifier.
>
> If however your categories are has_vocals, dance, soundtrack, pop,
>   then the classes are not mutually exclusive; for example, there can be
>   a piece of pop music that comes from a soundtrack and in addition has
>   vocals. In this case, it would be more appropriate to build 4 binary
>   logistic regression classifiers. This way, for each new musical piece,
>   your algorithm can separately decide whether it falls into each of the
>   four categories.